# SQL Formula Answer is Different from Excel Formula

Tags: sql, excel

I have a query which surmises data according to station which i have selected. In my sql table i have a column which is created by dividing column 1 with Column 2 *1000 it works but if i was to do the same thing in excel i get another answer :S.

```
SELECT [Client],[Station],[Saleshouse],[Terr vs# Sat],[Month],[Year 2],
sum([Hour]) as 'Hour',
sum ([Impacts]) as 'Impacts',
sum (nullif([Insertions],0)) as Insertions,
sum (nullif([Final Cost],0)) as FinalCost,
sum (nullif([Resp 1],0)) as 'Resp 1',
sum (nullif([Resp 2],0)) as 'Resp 2',
sum (nullif([Final Cost],0)/nullif([Resp 1],0)) as 'CPR 1',
sum (nullif([Resp 1],0)/nullif(([Impacts]*1000),0)) as 'Resp%',
sum (nullif([Final Cost],0)/nullif([Resp 2],0)) as 'CPR 2',
sum (nullif([Resp 2],0)/nullif([Impacts]*1000,0)) as 'Resp%2',
sum (nullif([Resp 1],0)/ nullif([Resp 2],0)) as 'New vistor/all visitor' 
FROM [Exporter].[dbo].[tbl_Television_Data]
WHERE [Station] ='4MUSIC'
GROUP BY [Client],[Station],[Saleshouse],[Terr vs# Sat],[Month],[Year 2] ORDER BY [Station]
```

The coulmn which im talking about is RESP% i get an answer of  0.0365374676389937
But within excel i use that same fromula method and i get this 0.00283685.

as you can see they are differnt yet use the same values :S.

Anyone able to give a answer on whats happening??

Comment: What are the values being divided?  What dos the query have to do with the question?  It has no columns called "column 1" or "column 2".

Comment: Show us the Excel formula too with actual column names.

Comment: I would think it has somthing to do with the number of decimal places it going to. When caculating the 2 seperate sums, SQL has more numbers and is rounding up more than excel, just a guess but the query seems good to me on a quick scan

Comment: @DevN00B: the answer will be different values used in each calculation. But we can't tell given how poor this question is...

Comment: The values which are being divided are Resp 1 = 235.44 and Impacts is 83.

Comment: The excel formula is basically adding the rows which are relevant to 4MUSIC which could mean row 1,5,8 etc.

Comment: When i comes to the decimal places it seems like its the same answer as stated in the question, i originally thought of but it seems not the case :(

Comment: Seems maybe like a case of "excel treats blank (null) cells as zero, sql ignores null" to me, but you have what looks like a null coercion there so maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the question is tagged with MySQL, but the syntax used looks suspiciously like SQL-Server, as such I will do all the demonstrations with SQL-Server syntax.

Secondly, based on the magnitude of the error (to the order of 10), I think you have your calculations mixed up, you appear to be saying that in the below 3 columns

```
sum ([Impacts]) as 'column1',
sum (nullif([Resp 2],0)) as 'column2',
sum (nullif([Resp 2],0)/nullif([Impacts]*1000,0)) as 'column3'
```

the third column is not giving you the same result as if you did the `(column2 / (column1 * 1000)` in excel, however this is not the same formula. I think what you need is:

```
NULLIF(SUM([Resp 2]), 0) / (NULLIF(SUM(Impacts) * 1000, 0) AS [Resp 2%]
```

Imagine this simple example (I have removed the `NULLIF` operators to make the difference between the equations more clear):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([Resp 2] FLOAT, [Impacts] FLOAT);
INSERT @T VALUES (132.44, 40), (103, 43);

SELECT  Resp2 = SUM([Resp 2]),
        Impacts = SUM(Impacts),
        YourCalc = SUM([Resp 2] / ([Impacts] * 1000)),
        MyCalc = SUM([Resp 2]) / (SUM(Impacts) * 1000)
FROM    @T;
```

This will give you:

```
+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| Resp2  | Impacts |     YourCalc       |       MyCalc       |
|--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------|
| 235.44 |   83    | 0.0057063488372093 | 0.0028366265060241 |
+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

As you can see `MyCalc` pretty much matches what you are expecting (the difference is probably due to rounding), but your calc does not (I did not fancy using trial and error to get your calc to match 0.0365374676389937 but hopefully you get the idea).